# typedef & function pointer

Tags: c++, typedef

I am recently saw some code, I am especially not clear of similar function pointer?

and below are function pointer.

I also is confused about below three function, the parameter type is "cairo_output_stream_t", but the cairo_output_stream_t structure contain member of there three function pointer. I can not understand what below function are doing.

```
typedef cairo_status_t
(*cairo_output_stream_write_func_t) (cairo_output_stream_t *output_stream,
                                     const unsigned char   *data,
                                     unsigned int           length);

typedef cairo_status_t
(*cairo_output_stream_flush_func_t) (cairo_output_stream_t *output_stream);

typedef cairo_status_t
(*cairo_output_stream_close_func_t) (cairo_output_stream_t *output_stream);

struct _cairo_output_stream {
    cairo_output_stream_write_func_t write_func;
    cairo_output_stream_flush_func_t flush_func;
    cairo_output_stream_close_func_t close_func;
    unsigned long                    position;
    cairo_status_t                   status;
    int                              closed;
};
```

cairo_status_t is an enum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's basically being done is a C-like way to emulate C++'s `this` pointer ... you pass a pointer to the `struct` as the first argument to the function call, and from that pointer you can call "methods" of the struct (in this case they are function pointers) and/or access data-members of the struct.

So for instance, you might have code using this style of programming that looks something like the following:

```
struct my_struct
{
    unsigned char* data;
    void (*method_func)(struct my_struct* this_pointer);
};

struct my_struct object;
//... initialize the members of the structure

//make a call using one of the function pointers in the structure, and pass the 
//address of the structure as an argument to the function so that the function
//can access the data-members and function pointers in the struct
object.method_func(&object);
```

Now `method_func` can access the `data` member of the `my_struct` instance in the same way a C++ class method can access its class-instance non-static data-members through the `this` pointer.

Comment: I see some code, and I am very not understand this expression"typedef void (*callback)(void);", do you know what meaning of my quoted typedef mean?

Comment: Yes.  The typedef `callback` is a pointer to a function that takes no arguments (i.e., it's `void`) and returns no values since the return type is `void`.  BTW, you may want to make sure the callback  argument type wasn't a `void*`, in which case the function that calls your callback will pass you some block of data.